# SOQL query limts

Tags: soql

While I am trying to run this SOQL query:

```
SELECT Company, Website FROM Lead LIMIT 25
```

It is returning only 12 rows instead of 25. Can anyone help me in figuring out this issue?

Answer (score 5):

`LIMIT 25` means that it will return maximum of 25 records (if there are more than 25 returned in the original query).

By the looks of it, either there are only 12 leads in the system, or you have access to only 12. Check the security model and sharing rules on the Lead object.